# What is the correct abbreviation for the word "numbers"?

Tags: abbreviations

What is the correct abbreviation for the words *numbers* and *number*?

- Nos.
- No.
- Nos
- No

Possible example usage:

1. "Number of guests" where the word number is abbreviated
2. "Numbers 10–15 are located in the top shelf."

Comment: The shortest expression is just #.

Comment: Sometimes there is a separate abbreviation for it... №

Comment: Does anyone find it odd when an abbreviation includes one or more letters that do not appear in the word being abbreviated?

Comment: @onomatomaniak The hash sign # is *not* a common or standard indication for 'number' in the UK. I do not know whether it is used in other English-speaking countries outside the US.

Comment: @user45992 I believe the 'o' in the abbreviation for 'number' comes from 'numero' (or a similar foreign word). *lb* & *oz* also include letters not in the corresponding *English* word. And where does the *$* symbol come from - no 'S' in *dollar*.

Comment: There are actually very few places you rellay need to abbreviate a word that is already short enough.
Some people spend time on saving a few letters, ending up in different inconsistent ways of abbreviating, when it in the long run actually becomes a cost and waste as it yields confusion.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that there is a global standard. It differs based on practice and the standards set by the relevant authorities (publishers and the like).

Ex: The [Oxford Journal Instructions for Authors](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/cesifo/for_authors/index.html)  suggests (Sec. 2.3):

> Abbreviations where the last letter of the singular word is not included take a full stop (vol., vols./ed., eds.). The abbreviation for number is no./nos. Abbreviated unit of measurements do not take a full stop (lb, mm, kg) and do not take a final 's' in the plural.

[This](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/no_5) is a suggestion from Cambridge Dictionary for use of *no.* as the abbreviation for number.

Comment: But no. is surely the abbreviation for "number" and nos. is the abbreviation for "numbers" in the Oxford Instructions. The "do not take a final 's' in the plural" only applies to lb, mm, kg, and so forth, and is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Both Oxford and Cambridge links explain the usage for "Client No. 5" but I don't see an answer for the case "Number of guests". Anyone have an answer to that one?

Comment: Covered in that definition: "No. of guests."

Answer (score 16):

Cambridge dictionary only gives the abbreviation *no.* when number refers to a numeral, a position or identification, not a quantity, amount or calculation : http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/number_1

Therefore I understand "Number of guests" should not be abbreviated.

In other words, the *ordinal number* (e.g. No. 3, which indicates a position in an ordered list) is abbreviated, but the *cardinal number* (e.g. Number of guests, which indicates a numeric quantity) is not abbreviated.

Comment: I don't think the number need necessarily be an ordinal; what is important is that "no." is used with a number to *identify* something.  The fact that two widgets have serial nos. 29432100 and 29432200 does not mean that there were 29,432,099 widgets produced before the first, nor that there were necessarily 99 widgets produced between them--it merely means that those numbers identify the widgets in question.

Answer (score 10):

I use "num" or "nm" instead of "no" to avoid confusion with "yes/no" meaning -- especially in my computer programming variable names.

Comment: I use `nof`, which means "number of". Instead of `nm_eggs_in_basket`, `nof_eggs_in_basket`.

Comment: Indeed, using "no" can lead to confusion: `test_validates_reference_no_format`

Answer (score 5):

Per [Wikipedia — Numero sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign), it's also possible to use " **Nº** " and " **No̲** ":

> The numero sign or numero symbol, № (also represented as Nº, No̲, No. or no.), is a typographic abbreviation of the word number(s) indicating ordinal numeration, especially in names and titles.
>
> For example, with the numero sign, the written long-form of the address "Number 22 Acacia Avenue" is shortened to "**№ 22 Acacia Avenue**", yet both forms are spoken long.

Though it  [doesn't seem to be common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign#English).