# How to denote a number if # cannot be used? (What are alternatives to # symbol?)

Tags: abbreviations, symbols

I have data file containing titles like

> Invoice #ZT-123456 June 2017

or

> Agreement #1_ABCD Foo Services

but I need to put these titles into an app where character `#` is not allowed. (Edit: And U.S. customer will see what I wrote there.)

What is the best alternative writing when I cannot use `#`?

I was thinking about something like this:

> Invoice Nr. ZT-123456

or

> Invoice nr. ZT-123456

Maybe I could use `number` but replacing symbol with complete word does not seem appropriate to me in this context.

Comment: This is not an English question.  Call it whatever you want.

Comment: "No." is the usual English abbreviation for "Number".

Comment: @MaxWilliams – I want this is to feel natural to U.S. customer. I am not sure if they will be happy if I call it any way I want.

Comment: If you're not under length restrictions, just spell it all out: "Invoice number".

Comment: The Numero sign №  (U+2116) can also be rendered as either No or N plus superscript 'o'. Also used is 'Nr' which I'm familiar with from use in Bills of Quantity where it has gradually taken over from № during the length of my career (going on 40 years) though I believe it is originally german. №t sure why it has changed, possibly more pan-european specification going on and it avoids the risk of laymen thinking it means 'none'.

Comment: @JohnLawler **& others** – just create your answers, I'll award them.

Comment: @miroxlav, i beg your pardon, I misread your question as being about variable names or something, not customer-facing values.

Comment: @MaxWilliams – I see, no problem. I edited the question for greater clarity.

Comment: related: [What Is the Real Name of the #?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161720/what-is-the-real-name-of-the) and [When to pronounce # for pound, sharp, hash or hashtag?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255912/when-to-pronounce-for-pound-sharp-hash-or-hashtag) and [What is the correct abbreviation for the word “numbers”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43095/what-is-the-correct-abbreviation-for-the-word-numbers)

Comment: There is no need to have any symbol, unless there is some potential for confusion with count, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard American English abbreviation for number is "No." (uppercase N, lowercase o, followed by a period). For example, Invoice No. 65967.

> No., no. written abbreviation
>
> number. room No.145
>
> Source: Kernerman English Multilingual Dictionary © 2006-2013