# Is nr. a correct abbreviation for the word number?

Tags: british-english, abbreviations

I'm a native German speaker. My daughter is learning (British) English in school. She wrote her first English test and got it back from the teacher now.

I'm surprised the title of the test was

> class test nr.1

Is *nr.* a common abbreviation for the word number in (British) English? I was expecting the abbreviation *no*.

The answers to these questions didn't help me:

- [How to denote a number if # cannot be used? (What are alternatives to # symbol?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406241/how-to-denote-a-number-if-cannot-be-used-what-are-alternatives-to-symbol/406245#406245)
- [Why does "No" mean "Number?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459968/why-does-no-mean-number)

It's not clear to me if

> the availability of other abbreviations like "Num." or "Nr." or "#"

means it's available in English or if it'd just be a "natural" choice.

The [Wikipedia numero sign page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign) isn't giving a final answer either.

[One Minute English](https://oneminuteenglish.org/en/abbreviation-number-nr-or-no/) shows the use in British English but without the colon.

[This answer](https://www.englishforums.com/English/NrOrNo/bndxhz/post.htm) on englishforums.com claims it's not correct English.

Edit: Changed the wording from *correct* to *common*.

Comment: Normally we use 'nr' as an abbreviation of 'near', and 'no' to abbreviate 'number' (from Latin *numero*). Moreover, unlike AmE, abbreviations do not usually end with a stop if they comprise the first and last letter of the word. So in BrE we have and Mr and Dr, in AmE they use Mr. and Dr. But because the abbreviation 'no' is easily confused with the word 'no', we usually capitalise it with a stop, like **No. 1** or with a superscipt like **Nº 1**.

Comment: "One Minute English" seems to be the personal website of some guy named Conor, so you don't seem to have any really reputable sources that indicate that "nr" is a valid abbreviation for "number".

Comment: I don't think that historically the **#** was much used in BrE, but is routinely seen and understood.

Comment: @StuartF: Why is this obvious? There are norms and standards for similar things. And I am quite sure there's a standard way/convention for doing this in scientific papers. Furthermore,  maybe not everyone here is working or has studied in the field of linguistics and thus doesn't know there's no "official list"? Why are there questions like mine on other pages? Anyway: I'm going to change the wording from "correct" to "common".

Comment: It is included in the [Oxford Reference Dictionary of Abbreviations](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199698295.001.0001/acref-9780199698295-e-70985?rskey=3SV5qW&result=72738). Lower case, last entry in the list. But I'd say it's unusual and better avoided. And note the lack of a full stop.

Comment: This question would require a great deal of effort to be answered other than subjectively. From your bio. I gather you are in the US. In Britain my experience is that "No." is used in the vast majority of cases, but other Brits may have a different experience. Perhaps "nr." is part of an American de-latinization movement that I assume is responsible for the creeping use of "ex" in place of "e.g.".

Comment: No. 1 OR Nbr. 1 but there is no official abbreviation for the word number in English.

Answer (score 1):

*Nr* is not a common abbreviation for *number* in British English. It will almost certainly be understood, but it does indicate a non-native speaker — for this particular abbreviation, a German speaker of English who has simply used the customary German abbreviation.

The only customary abbreviation for *number* in British English is *no.*

Collins has

> **[No.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no)**
>
> No. is a written abbreviation for number.
>
> > That year he was named the nation's No. 1 college football star.
> > Columbia Law Review, vol. no. 698 p1317.

and

> **[nr](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nr)**
>
> in British English:
> abbreviation for **near**

There is no mention of *nr* for *number.*

Collins does mention #, but notes it as American and not British. Again, it's likely to be understood in British English, but as an Americanism.

> **[number sign](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/number-sign)**
>
> in American English:
> a symbol (#) for “number” or “numbered”
>
> > item #8 on the list

Comment: [Acronym(sic) Finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/NR.html) lists the _number_ expansion of 'NR' (I'm not sure how they treat capitalisation in their data-gathering) ahead of even _near_.

Comment: Well, that's a matter of perceived reliability, I think. But instead of carping about each answer, why not write one?

Comment: My comment from 2 years ago: 'It is included in the Oxford Reference Dictionary of Abbreviations. Lower case, last entry in the list. But I'd say it's unusual and better avoided. And note the lack of a full stop.' So I'd say best **not** 'answered' on POB grounds.

Comment: Except it isn't opinion-based. There are documented sources. They may differ, in which case it's up to the OP to accept an answer, as always. The **answers** are not mere opinion.

Comment: Answers using cherry-picked resources / a non-balanced survey are statistically unsound and subjective (they are dependent on who's cherry-picking or using an inadequate sample).

Comment: Fine. ***Write a better answer.*** Stop carping in comments.

Comment: But my answer would include your references as well as the ORDA reference.

Answer (score -1):

It is not included in the Oxford English Dictionary list of abbreviations starting with 'n':

[OED list of 'n' abbreviations](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/#n)

Comment: But it _is_ included in the [Oxford Reference Dictionary of Abbreviations](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199698295.001.0001/acref-9780199698295-e-70985?rskey=3SV5qW&result=72738). Lower case, last entry. The list you point to is just the list of abbreviations actually used in OED and is far from comprehensive.

Comment: Oh, ok. Very helpful, thank you!